# MomentJS keeps defaulting date to GMT

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, momentjs

I have

```
moment(line.dateRange[0], 'DD-MM-YY HH:mm').toDate()
```

set up, where the input is a string: `15-10-2021 09:00`

Moment keeps outputting:  `2020-10-15T07:00:00.000Z`, even though my `process.env.TZ` of my nodeJS server is `Europe/Amsterdam`.

```
for (const line of orderLines) {
      
    let orderLine = {
            bookingID: bookingDB.id,
            bookingStart: moment(line.dateRange[0], 'DD-MM-YY HH:mm').format(),
            bookingEnd: moment(line.dateRange[1], 'DD-MM-YY HH:mm').format(),
            productID: line.productID,
            type: line.type
         }
         console.log(orderLine)
         lines.push(orderLine);
      }
      const orderLinesDB = await BookingLine.bulkCreate(lines);
      console.log(orderLinesDB)
      res.status(200).send(orderLinesDB);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you're seeing the output `2020-10-15T07:00:00.000Z` because you're doing:

```
console.log(moment('15-10-2021 09:00', 'DD-MM-YY HH:mm').toDate())
```

What you're seeing in the output is UTC time, which will be 2 hours behind Europe/Amsterdam, since Node.js calls toISOString() when logging dates.

Try calling [moment.format()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to see local time, *or* use [.toDate().toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) or [.toDate().toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString).

For example:

```
const input = '15-10-2021 09:00';

console.log('UTC time:', moment(input, 'DD-MM-YY HH:mm').toDate())
console.log('Local time:', moment(input, 'DD-MM-YY HH:mm').format())
console.log('Local time (II):', moment(input, 'DD-MM-YY HH:mm').toDate().toLocaleString())
console.log('Local time (III):', moment(input, 'DD-MM-YY HH:mm').toDate().toString())
```

Should output

```
 UTC time: 2020-10-15T07:00:00.000Z
 Local time: 2020-10-15T09:00:00+02:00
 Local time (II): 15/10/2020, 09:00:00
 Local time (III): Thu Oct 15 2020 09:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

Which is what we would expect.

Comment: Yes, the first option works, kind of.. If I log it, then I will will be the correct format, but once i retrieve the saved datetimes from the MySQL it will change the format again

Comment: Could you maybe add a short snippet showing how you save the date to MySQL, this will help diagnose any issue there? Thanks!

Comment: Added the snippet, I use Sequelize

Comment: I believe that's the same issue manifesting in another guise, once you have read a date back from the database, e.g. bookingStart, can you try doing bookingStart.toString() or bookingStart.toLocaleString() ? This should give you the local time rather than UTC.